# How to get sfmc user info inside custom activity in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I'm building a custom activity for Journey Builder. I have successfully created and hosted the Custom Activity UI for configuring the parameters that will be sent at the time of execution.

But the issue is that, while configuring I need to fetch some data from an api, that requires some sort of authentication.

All I get from SFMC in my custom activity is 2 tokens (in the broadcasted event `requestedTokens`), but I can't use those for anything. As per my design, I want to get some user info of current SFMC user configuring the custom activity e.g. email, user id etc. and then I will validate that against a custom db.

Thanks.